# removeChild(lastChild) not working?

Tags: javascript

I take on some tutorials on accessing and manipulating the DOM and i came across this:

I have this HTML:

```
<span>
    Shooting
    <img id="fallenstar" src="https://dom-tutorials.appspot.com/static/star_on.gif">
</span>
```

I want to remove the star and i figured out this solution:

```
document.getElementById("fallenstar").parentNode.removeChild(lastChild);
```

but it doesn't work while this works:

```
var star = document.getElementById('fallenstar');
star.parentNode.removeChild(star);
```

My question is what is the difference between them. Why it works when i assign the     `document.getElementById("fallenstar")` into a variable?

Comment: Well what is `lastChild`?

Comment: As a sidenote, you'd really better do it via CSS.

Comment: What about the text node after the img?

Comment: i was confused with the PROPERTY .lastChild .Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare `lastChild`. I assume is the star image:

```
var lastChild = document.getElementById('fallenstar');
lastChild.parentNode.removeChild(lastChild);
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu3dwnp4/1/)

Comment: Why bother referencing `#fallenstar` again?

Comment: Are you *certain* that the lastChild is the img element in all browsers?

Comment: @RobG's question is good, because the lastChild could possibly be a whitespace textNode in some browsers.  @Alek's answer always works, although the variable name `lastChild` may be misleading.  His second line could be simplified to `lastChild.parentNode.removeChild(lastChild);`

Answer (score 3):

The variable `lastChild` is not defined anywhere. Hence, it cannot be used as an argument to the `removeChild` function.

Answer (score 0):

Given the markup:

```
<span>
    Shooting
    <img id="fallenstar" src="https://dom-tutorials.appspot.com/static/star_on.gif">
</span>
```

The last child of the span element is a text node, not the img element. The way to remove the image reliably in all browsers is to reference it directly:

```
var node = document.getElementById('fallenstar');
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Comment: Why isn't it the img? Sorry for my question but i am still in early learning phase.I really thought that the order is    text node == first and that img == last child

Comment: @PanagiotisIliakopoulos: at least in Chrome the new line after the `<img>` element creates a new text node, which means that the `<img>` element is not the last child of the `<span>` element.